# What is the difference between a browser request and a Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I am working in a JSF application which uses JSF 1.2 version. As we know JSF 1.2 do not support ajax. In my application, I need to use value change listener. But I am not getting the expected result. I was suggested to use ajax tags to get better results for value change listeners. I have seen value change listeners are working in ajax tags also (in JSF 2.X versions).

I want to know what is happening (in behind the browser) in a normal form request and in a ajax request. Please explain me with a example for both the cases.

Comment: What research have you done so far? Researching is a big part of learning. If you've done some research, please explain what you've found out and what you don't understand about it.

Comment: I have used ajax requests. In Ajax, It is passing the request through the xml with the help of scripting language like javascript and get results in the form of xml. Finally without refresing the entire page it decodes the result from the xml formatted result and shows that in the html/jsp page. But this is what I have understood from my perception. I want some detailed explanation about all the actions happening in the background for both requests. I know it looks like a repeated question. But I am not able to get a detailed explanation from the already asked questions.

Answer (score 2):

An AJAX request is likely to browser request as per your server behaviour. But main difference is comes when Header Request perform on bahlf of HTTP headers.Like Google Chrome indicate their header request as :

X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
And each browser has their own header request format to send in a different way but main dependent is client.

But the browser makes a regular request as in window.location.href = "index.html", it clears the current window and loads the server response into the window.

While handling request with an ajax, the current window/document is unaffected and javascript code can examine the results of the request and do what it wants to with those results (insert HTML dynamically into the page, parse JSON and use it the page logic, parse XML, etc...). It depend what type of response you are dealing with in your format.
" At the new phase on the server it is more common to use GET for AJAX calls. This is because when using XMLHttpRequest browsers implement POST as a two-step process (sending the headers first and then the data). This means that GET requests are more responsive – something you need in AJAX environments! Because “Ajax” requests are subject to the same origin policy there is limited security risks when using GET instead of POST. Use GET to “GET” information from the server such as loading a JavaScript file (AJAX shorthand function $.getScript() can be used to do this) or loading a JSON file (AJAX shorthand function $.getJSON() can be used to do this)".
Ex. jQuery AJAX Functions that use GET as default:

```
    $.get(), $.getScript(), $.getJSON(), .load()

  $.ajax({
     url: 'getTwitterFollowers.php',
     type: 'GET',
     data: 'twitterUsername=jquery4u',
     success: function(data) {
     //called when successful
     $('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
     },
     error: function(e) {
     //called when there is an error
     //console.log(e.message);
 }
});
```